# environment variable isn't read in bash script

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, aws

I'm deploying a nodejs app to a EC2 instance on AWS through codecommit/codebuild/codedeploy. In my appspec.yml file for codedeploy, I have a script called application_start.sh, which is called when the application starts. I use it to restart pm2.

```
#!/bin/bash

pm2 delete /home/ubuntu/server/app.js 2> /dev/null
CREDENTIALS_SOURCE=$CREDENTIALS_SOURCE pm2 start /home/ubuntu/server/app.js --update-env
```

As you can see, I have an env variable ($CREDENTIALS_SOURCE) which I read in the bash script to set an env variable for my nodejs code.

The problem is: when the script runs the first time (automatically through the aws pipeline), the $CREDENTIALS_SOURCE variable isn't read and the server crashes. When I SSH into the server and I execute the exact same commands as like in the sh-script, it works.

When I change the bash script to `CREDENTIALS_SOURCE=dev`, so hardcoding "dev" instead of reading it out from the server env variable, it also works.

I have `export CREDENTIALS_SOURCE=dev` in .bashrc (and sourced it). When I do `printenv` I see the environment variable.

Comment: Where are you expecting to set the value of the variable when you run this through the aws pipeline?

Comment: If you get this varible outside the script `CREDENTIALS_SOURCE=$CREDENTIALS_SOURCE` is 100% redundant and does absolutely nothing. Where do you define this variable? You could simply add something like `. /script/which/defines/cred_source.sh` or `CREDENTIALS_SOURCE=$(cat /some/file)`

Comment: Does shebang `#!/bin/bash -l` help ?

Comment: the variable is set on the server, not in the aws process itself

Comment: How is it set? For whom? Where? If where it's set and this script run independently, your script cannot know about that. Again, `CREDENTIALS_SOURCE=$CREDENTIALS_SOURCE` is 100% nonsensical and **cannot** possibly work. You define a variable which is supposedly already defined e.g. via `export`. You can remove this statement and the script will continue to work in your SSH shell because `$CREDENTIALS_SOURCE` is set as a bash env variable.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov `VAR=$VAR` is not nonsensical if followed by a command directly, it works as if the variable was exported to the command. E.g. `var=1 ; bash -c 'echo $var'` versus `var=1 ; var=$var bash -c 'echo $var'`

Comment: @choroba yet `export var=1; bash -c 'echo $var'` - works exactly like it should. Your first example doesn't work because var in it is a local variable. In the context of this situation `VAR=$VAR command` doesn't make any sense as `$VAR` is not defined earlier by anything.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov You're right, I just wouldn't say "100% nonsensical" when it depends on the situation.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov when I remove the ``CREDENTIALS_SOURCE=$CREDENTIALS_SOURCE``from the statement, I get a nodejs error saying the env variable is undefined. Echo'ing the variable on the server still works. Changing to ``CREDENTIALS_SOURCE=dev`` (so dev "hardcoded) fixes it. but I want it from a env variable from the server.

Comment: I'm trying to deploy from an AWS pipeline to an EC2 instance. I have a script "application_start.sh" which runs on application start during the CodeDeploy phase. If I SSH into the server and run this script myself, everything works.

Comment: Add `. /path/to/application_start.sh` at the beginning of your script. Yes, that's "dot space ..."

Comment: the path is added, the script is executed because I see in the pm2 logs that the server has restarted. But when the server restarts from the script, it doesn't read the env variable. When I restart pm2 myself through the shell, it works.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, it works but I don't know if this is the way to go.

Clearly, pm2 can't read env variables from the server. When I run `node app.js` instead of `pm2 start app.js`, the env variable is accessible for the nodeJS app.

With the following command, I got it working for pm2:

```
sudo -E pm2 start app.js
```

My guess is that the env variable is not stored in the ubuntu user, but in the root (sudo) user. Is this correct?

---

The above isn't a perfect solution. A better solution:

1. add `export CREDENTIALS_SOURCE=dev` to `/etc/profile`
2. add `source /etc/profile` in `application_start.sh` before starting `pm2`

This works!

Sources:

- [environment variable isn't read in bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705190/environment-variable-isnt-read-in-bash-script?noredirect=1#comment1334637_705190)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360549/node-js-app-cant-access-any-env-variables-when-pm2-is-started-from-a-script-but